# hailstone sequence using recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

Does it make sense to implement using recursion? I wrote some bad solution below.
Please correct me

```
def hailstone(n):
    if(n<0):
        print("Invalid input")
        return None
    if(n==1):
        print(1)
        return None
    if(n%2 == 0):
        print(n)
        hailstone(n/2)
    if(n%2==1):
        print(n)
        hailstone((n*3) + 1)
```

My question:

How do i move `n<0` condition to a right place? Did i miss or add extra return statement?

Comment: You're missing a `:` on your fourth if

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not that bad, it is a simple recursive solution, which will give you the hailstone sequence for small `n`'s without problems. There seem to be one missing colon as pointed out bu `sshashank124`, and you should have `n<=0` instead of `n<0`.

However, recursion should generally not be used when the recursive function is called only once from within the function itself. In that case recursion is essentially a loop. In your case the equivalent functionality can be obtained by:

```
def hailstone(n):
    if(n<=0):
        print("Invalid input")
        return None
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            n = 3*n + 1
        else:
            n = n / 2
        print n
    return None
```

In any case, I suggest you post your code to the code review site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

(As to your question, you may have several `return` statements in a function. Another - usually better - possibility is to raise an error when you receive bad input.)

If you want to calculate the sequence lengths for a large number of `n`'s, then your algorithm is not necessarily the best performing one.

Comment: It's more idiomatic to use `if not n % 2` and use the implicit "falseness" of 0 as opposed to `if n % 2 == 1

Comment: @IanAuld: Personally, I'd just use `if n & 1` despite its being a c'ism, because that is the construct I read fastest... I tried to keep the code as close to the OP's form and style as possible. But, yes, there is a reason why I suggested exposing the code to the nice people of codereview.

Comment: @DrV i see multiple `return None` in your code. In a function, if i do not mention this, will python function implicitly does not `return None`?

Comment: @overexchange: I just put the `return None` there because the code in the question uses it. You may use a `return` without any return value, and you do not need to have any return value. So, the code in my answer may be modified by 1. removing the last `return` and 2. by changing the first `return None` into a plain `return`. The best alternative would be to replace the first `return None` by `raise ValueError('input value has to be > 0')`to raise an exception if a bad input value is given.

Comment: @DrV i think, whether we use `return None` or just `return` or `no return all`, the function will return None in all 3 cases.

Comment: @DrV I did not get this statement: `recursion should generally not be used when the recursive function is called only once from within the function itself.`, i think function is being called multiple times from within.